# sign symbol above or below the sigma operator

Tags: variance, covariance, notation, acf-pacf

the below two expressions are the same according some references, so, my question is, why does it change the sign in $Y_{i+k}$ or $Y_{i-k},$ when there is a plus or a minus sign above or below the $\sum.$ Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This looks the numerator of (one flavour of)  autocorrelation or  autocovariance. The first regards the result as assigned to positions $1$ onwards, so the index $i$ is the start of the window. The second regards it as assigned to positions $k + 1$ onwards, so $i$ is the end of the window. Collectively the results will be same. The positioning of indexes relative to the summation sign is a cosmetic or stylistic detail: the choice depends on a style preference for use of vertical and horizontal space.

Comment: This isn't about $\sigma$-fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be dealing with the numerator of an autocorrelation of lag $k.$

First, let's use exactly the same notation for the two sums $T_1$ and $T_2,$ and reverse the order of the product in the second sum:

$$T_1=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} (Y_i-\bar Y)(Y_{i+k}-\bar Y),$$
$$T_2=\sum_{i=k+1}^n (Y_{i-k}-\bar Y)(Y_i - \bar Y).$$

Now, let's look at the specific case where $n=10$ and lag $k =6,$ so that

$$T_1=\sum_{i=1}^{10-6} (Y_i-\bar Y)(Y_{i+6}-\bar Y) = \sum_{i=1}^{4} (Y_i-\bar Y)(Y_{i+6}-\bar Y),$$
$$T_2=\sum_{i=k+1}^{10} (Y_{i-6}-\bar Y)(Y_i - \bar Y) = \sum_{i=7}^{10} (Y_{i-6}-\bar Y)(Y_i - \bar Y).$$

We can see that each sum has four terms. Explicitly, write out the four terms for each:

In $T_1,$ the index runs from $i = 1$ to $i=4:$

$$T_1 = (Y_1-\bar Y)(Y_7-\bar Y)+(Y_2-\bar Y)(Y_8-\bar Y) \\
+ (Y_3-\bar Y)(Y_9-\bar Y)+(Y_4 -\bar Y)(Y_{10}-\bar Y).$$

In $T_2,$ the index runs from $i = 7$ to $i = 10:$
$$T_2 = (Y_1-\bar Y)(Y_7-\bar Y)+(Y_2-\bar Y)(Y_8-\bar Y) \\
+ (Y_3-\bar Y)(Y_9-\bar Y)+(Y_4 -\bar Y)(Y_{10}-\bar Y),$$

So finally, we see that $T_1 = T_2.$

More generally, perhaps try the change of index variable $j = i+k$ to
change one sum to the other.